Let me know when new subtopic just started on YouTube
Assume a particular Youtube video is divided into subtopics (of TOC, table of contents). Is there a Firefox extension that would let me know while playing the video that it just crossed new subtopic? I'd like to have this event handler in the browser because I could be aware where in the video I am just now without clicking on the bottom bar of the video.

I assume you mean chapters, not "subtopics"?

@Destroy666 Probably yes, this may be called chapters.
